# Marginal independence does not imply joint independence

Tags: conditional-probability, random-variable, independence, conditional-expectation

Consider the random variables $X,Y,Z$.

Assume

$$
X\perp Z
$$

$$
Y\perp Z
$$

$$
X\perp Y
$$

Can we say 
$$
(X,Y)\perp Z
$$

My intuition is that we can't because
$$
p_{X,Y}=p_X\times p_Y=p_{X|Z} \times p_{Y|Z} \neq p_{X,Y|Z}
$$

Could you provide also some example?

---

Viceversa, suppose for some random variables $Q,A,B$ we have that 
$$
Q\perp(A,B)
$$
Does this imply $Q\perp A$ and $Q\perp B$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first question assumes that $X, Y$, and $Z$ are *pairwise* independent random variables and asks whether 
$$
X,Y, Z~~\text{pairwise independent} \implies (X,Y)~~\text{and}~~Z~~\text{independent}??\tag{1}
$$
In general, the answer is NO, the implication $(1)$ does not hold in all cases. The proof of this is by a *reductio ad absurdum* argument: if
the implication $(1)$ were to hold, then pairwise independence of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ would imply that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are mutually independent which we know is not true in general.

Suppose that implication $(1)$ is true. Then,
$$p_{X,Y,Z} = \underbrace{p_{X,Y}\cdot p_Z}_{(X,Y)\perp Z ~\text{via}~(1)} 
= \underbrace{p_{X}\cdot p_Y}_{X\perp Y~\text{by hypothesis}}\cdot p_Z$$
and so $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are mutually independent which is not true in general. So, it must be that the hypothesis that $(1)$ holds is
false.

The simplest example of pairwise independent random variables that are not mutually independent random variables is $X, Y$, and $Z$ being *Bernoulli*$(\frac 12)$ random variables whose joint pmf has value
$\frac 14$ when $(X,Y,Z)$ equals $(0,0,0)$ or $(0,1,1)$ or $(1,0,1)$, or $(1,1,0)$. These are pairwise independent random variables but not mutually independent random variables. In particular, 
$$p_{X,Y,Z}(1,1,1) = 0 \neq p_{X,Y}(1,1)\cdot p_Z(1) = \frac 14\cdot \frac 12$$
and so $(X,Y)$ is *not independent* of $Z$ as you suspect. Indeed, it
is even possible to have standard normal random variables that are pairwise independent but are not mutually independent. See the first couple of paragraphs of [this answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/189206/6633) for a construction.

Your second question asks independence of $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ allows us to
deduce that $X$ and $Z$ are independent and that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, and here the answer is YES. We have that for discrete
random variables,
$$p_{X,Z} = \sum_y p_{X,Y,Z} = \sum_y \underbrace{p_{X,Y}\cdot p_Z}_{(X,Y)\perp Z}
= \left(\sum_y p_{X,Y}\right)\cdot p_Z = p_X\cdot p_Z$$
and similarly for $Y$ and $Z$, (and for continuous random variables when sums are replaced by integrals, etc).

Comment: Regarding question 1: you have shown that $(X,Y)\perp Z$ plus $X\perp Y$ implies that $X,Y,Z$ are mutually independent. Correct? Is it also true that $X,Y,Z$ mutually independent implies $(X,Y)\perp Z$? I would say yes because $p_{X,Y|Z}\equiv\frac{p_{X,Y,Z}}{p_Z}=\frac{p_X p_Y p_Z}{p_Z}=p_X p_Y=p_{X,Y}$ where the last step uses that mutual independence implies pairwise independence. Correct?

Comment: @user3285148 Yes, we don't really need pairwise independence of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$; $(X,Y)\perp Z$ plus $X \perp Y$ suffices for mutual independence.