# If $X, Y$ are independent of $Z$, is $P(X|Y, Z) = P(X|Y)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

If $X$ is independent of $Z$, and $Y$ is independent of $Z$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, is the following true:
\begin{align*}
P(X|Y, Z) &= \frac{P(X, Y, Z)}{P(Y, Z)}\\
&= \frac{P(X, Y)P(Z)}{P(Y)P(Z)}\\
&= \frac{P(X, Y)}{P(Y)}\\
&= P(X|Y)
\end{align*}

Comment: Marginally independent does not imply jointly independent: see this earlier [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276348/7224).

Comment: @Xi'an OP did not say the distributions are marginally independent. I think he/she used "independence" in the common sense.

Comment: This is only true if $X$ is conditionally independent of $Z$ given $Y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a counterexample

- Say the following events (for binary values of X, Y and Z) have equal probabilities.

  ```
  X Y Z   probability
  0 1 1   1/4
  1 0 1   1/4
  0 0 0   1/4
  1 1 0   1/4
  ```

  Then $P(X=1) = P(X=0) = 0.5$ and $P(Y=1) = P(Y=0) = 0.5$ independent from $Z$.

  But $P(X| Y,Z) = \text{XOR}(Y,Z)$ and *not* independent from $Y,Z$ (where $\text{XOR}$ refers to the [exclusive or](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or))

Comment: Would $P(X|Y, Z) = P(X|Y)$ if $(X, Y)$ is jointly independent of $Z$? In the counterexample above, it is assumed that $X$ and $Y$ are marginally independent of $Z$, correct?