# vector of three RVs that are pairwise Gaussian is Gaussian

Tags: probability, self-study

If $(X,Y)$, $(X,Z)$, and $(Y,Z)$ are all Gaussian, does it follow that $(X,Y,Z)$ is also Gaussian? I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a pair of Gaussian random variables for which the joint distribution is not Gaussian?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d)  A straightforward counterexample is to extend the example in the upper right figure in @whuber's answer to three dimensions.

Comment: Why do three normal random variable necessarily have to have a Gaussian joint distribution? They're not necessarily independent. @Konstantin

Comment: @Konstantin - Just being able to construct a covariance matrix does not mean the three variables are jointly Gaussian.

Comment: @jbowman Thank you, you are so right, I've learned from the post Jarle Tufto ponted at.

Comment: The example in the duplicate was posted by @Cardinal, not by me.  However, at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/434151/919 I recently posted an example of a triviariate distribution that has uniform 2D marginals but is not uniform.  By treating this as a copula one obtains an (intriguing) example involving pairwise Gaussian variables that are not jointly Gaussian, but in a subtle way. This approach extends to any univariate distribution whatsoever.

Comment: Not the one I was looking for, but e.g. see whuber's answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396687/derive-multivariate-from-bivariate-normal-distribution ... or my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305067/get-joint-distribution-from-pairwise-marginal-distribution/305069#305069 ... or see this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81469/if-any-two-variables-follow-a-normal-bivariate-distribution-does-it-also-have-a/81471#81471  ... any of those answers directly responds to this question. The third might be a good duplicate to add above