# How to check if two random Gaussian vectors are jointly Gaussian?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, joint-distribution, unbiased-estimator, estimators

Given the following system of equations:

$\textbf{y} = \textbf{x}_{1} + \sum_{l=2}^{L}\textbf{x}_{l} + \textbf{w}$

where $\textbf{y}$, $\textbf{x}_{l}, \; \forall l$ and $\textbf{w}$ are Gaussian random vectors with zero mean and variances $ \gt 0$.

How can we check if $\textbf{y}$ and $\textbf{x}_{1}$ are jointly Gaussian?

This question arises from the fact that the linear MMSE estimator of $\textbf{x}_{1}$ given $\textbf{y}$ becomes the Bayesian estimator when $\textbf{y}$ and $\textbf{x}_{1}$ are jointly Gaussian, however, I don't know if they are jointly Gaussian, and if so, how can I prove/check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot *check* if $y$ and $x_1$ are jointly Gaussian.  **If** *all* the $x_i$ *and* $w$ are known or assumed to be *jointly* Gaussian, not just individually Gaussian, then $y$ and $x_1$ are jointly Gaussian. Without the joint Gaussianity assumption following **If** in the previous sentence, $y$ and $x_1$ too are not jointly Gaussian except in very unusual circumstances.  For a simplified version of such unusual circumstances, see the answers to *[this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/189130/6633)* of mine.  But bear in mind that these are the exception, not the rule. The sum of Gaussian random variables that are *not* jointly Gaussian shouldn't be assumed to be a Gaussian random variable; it hardly ever is.