# Necessary condition for sum of normals to be a normal

Tags: normal-distribution

What is the **necessary** condition for a sum $Z=X+Y$ of two normal random variables $X$ and $Y$ to be a normal random variable?

If this is too difficult to state in general, what are some **sufficient** conditions for that (besides the well-known sufficient condition that the random vector $(X,Y)$ is multivariate normal)?

(A related thread [Is joint normality a necessary condition for the sum of normal random variables to be normal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189130/) exemplifies that joint normality is **not** a **necessary** condition.)

Comment: For some sufficient conditions, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4364.