# Multivariate normal distribution property

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, linearity

The Econonometrics book by Hansen mentions this property of a multivariate normal distribution:
If $X∼N(\mu,\Sigma)$ then $AX+b∼N(Aμ+b,AΣA^\prime)$. It goes to say that a simple implication of this that each individual $X_j$ in $X$ is univariate normal. Could someone please explain how is this implied from the linearity property?
Also is the converse true? If each $X_j$ in a $k$-vector random variable $X$ is normally distributed, is $X$ normally distributed?

Comment: X∼N(μ,Σ) is enough for saying Xj is univariate normal

Comment: Each $X_j$ is (in an obvious, trivial way) a linear transformation of $X,$ *qed.*  The converse is false: this is discussed in several nice threads, including https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159.  For a compendium of related results and characterizations of Normal distributions, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4364.

Comment: The reverse is not true; marginal normality is not enough to assure joint normality: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/189633/247274