# Conditions for gaussianity of sum of Gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

Under which conditions is the sum of a finite number of Gaussian random variables a Gaussian?

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, your question is a duplicate of [Is joint normality a necessary condition for the sum of normal random variables to be normal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189130/is-joint-normality-a-necessary-condition-for-the-sum-of-normal-random-variables)