# How to develop a model in R to illustrate that sum of two variables normally distributed if these two variables each follow a Normal distribution?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, mean, random-variable, standard-deviation

I was wondering how can I use code in R to set up a simulation to show that if two random variables each follow a normal distribution with given means and variances, their sum is also normally distributed with a mean equal to the sum of the means of two random variables and variance equal to the variances of the two random variables. 
[image: mean and standard deviation of two variables are given in this table]

Comment: x <- rnorm(N,a,b) + rnorm(N,a,b)?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/368345/99274.

Comment: Thank you all for help. I think I get it. @Dave

Comment: The statement implied in the title is false in general. The margins being normal is not sufficient to guarantee that their sum will be normal.